# update row counts in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

i want to update the row counts table of my own which 
is created in the datbase with the number of rows of each table in the db **(postgres)**

so i am trying out something like this but it is not working 
the function is replacing the count with 0 for each row

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "update_row_counts" (reltuples integer, relname text) 
RETURNS "pg_catalog"."void" AS 
    $body$  
      DECLARE 
      BEGIN 
      EXECUTE 'UPDATE row_counts set reltuples=' || reltuples || ' where relname = ''' || relname;  
      END;  
    $body$  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

SELECT update_row_counts(reltuples, relname),relname, reltuples  FROM pg_class pg, information_schema.tables i where
pg.relname = i.table_name and relkind='r' and table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
```

can any one help me

Comment: If you are going to select those values from `pg_class`, why don't you use a view instead?

Comment: can you give me the script i could not understand this how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are going to do some math and update this table latter (or also if you are doing some kind of snapshot), I see no point in doing it if you can simple create a view that queries `pg_class`, like:

```
CREATE VIEW row_counts AS
    SELECT relname, reltuples
    FROM pg_class pg, information_schema.tables i
    WHERE pg.relname = i.table_name
        AND relkind='r'
        AND table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
```

BTW, if you are doing this to get the number of rows of a table, notice that this result is **not exact**, which means it is an approximate value of the number of tuples in a table, and, sometimes, it can be really wrong. Just immediately after an `ANALYZE` is that this number is more accurate.

Comment: Matheus but i really need to update the table which is already there i cant create a view because application is using the same table

Comment: @SaravanaKumar, as I said, if your app only select from this table, you can drop the table and create a view with same name and your app will work as is. If your app update/insert/delete on it, then you cannot do that, though.

Comment: there are triggers which always updates the row_counts table whenever an insert or delete happens

Comment: @SaravanaKumar, do you really think this is a good idea? I don't, because UPDATEs on same tuple coming from triggers will cause horrible lock issues... Only use it if you understand this issues and you *really*, *REALLY*, **REALLY** need it...

Comment: i really need the update script for the row_counts table because i cant lose that table, the triggers are not affecting anywhere can you help me to get this update pl/sql script

Comment: @SaravanaKumar, Daniel's answer already covered that, I don't know what else you want. I just think your idea is really, *REALLY* bad (didn't I emphasize "REALLY" enough?)...

Answer (score 0):

`relname` is misquoted in your function, but you don't need `EXECUTE` anyway, it's simpler to do:

```
   UPDATE row_counts set reltuples=$1 where relname=$2
```

If you don't like `$1` and `$2` you may use the function parameter names, but in this case don't name them the same as the columns.
See  [Declaring Function Parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-ALIASES) in the doc.

Also the empty `DECLARE` section is not needed.

Comment: I replicated another script in order to obtain this but did not help me can you correct the script for me

Comment: Daniel Vérité is there a way i can perform this operation

Comment: @SaravanaKumar: not sure what operation you're referring to.

Comment: Daniel Vérité I need a pl/sql script to update the row_counts table with reltuples of each table which already has the names of all the table   the above one did not work out